# Image Filters are shared among cloned Object in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

I am using the latest version of `Fabirc.js`.This is how I am `cloning` Images .

```
var object = fabric.util.object.clone(_canvasObject.getActiveObject());

object.set("top", object.top+10);
object.set("left", object.left+10);
_canvasObject.add(object);
_canvasObject.renderAll();
```

But If I apply image filters to the cloned object, it is also shared by the original objects. How can this be solved?

Comment: could you share a fiddle please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the clone function you are calling is a object cloning utility stop at first level of cloning. It does not iterate over properties that are objects.

To properly clone an images use:

```
_canvasObject.getActiveObject().clone(function(cloned) {
  cloned.set("top", cloned.top+10);
  cloned.set("left", cloned.left+10);
  _canvasObject.add(cloned);
});
```

Comment: But I still dint understand why your solution works.Can u pls explain a bit on how your solution works

Comment: it is about fabricjs methods, you should read fabricjs.com/docs
clone does just a copy of an object. While fabricObject.clone() is a method written to make a copy of the object